# Пара вопросов чтобы выбрать хостинг.

Tags: joomla, хостинг

1.Какую посещаемость выдержит сайт на joomla средней загрузки хостинг 1000MHZ 512MB RAM?

2.Какие примерно должны быть параметры хостинга чтобы выдержать сайт на joomla с посещаймостью 5000 уников в день?

Comment: Joomla... Не завидую я вам. 500 точно выдержит. 1000 будет со скрипом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от выполняемых сайтом задач и кучи параметров хостинга (важного — производительности ввода-вывода, например), части которых вам никогда не скажут (например, в случае OpenVZ — насколько сильно VPSы оверселлят).

«Средний» сайт — совершенно бесполезное понятие, в данном случае. Можно сказать так, что сайт выдержит, грубо, 20 запросов в секунду. Грубо — потому что плюс-минус 19.95. Потому что в «среднем» сайте может оказаться как вылизаная до мелочей архитектура (и сайт будет летать), так и индийский код высшей пробы (и даже у одинокого юника будут тормоза).

Единственный вариант, который даст точные цифры — ставить и пробовать, [`ab(1)`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) в помощь. Некоторые хостеры, скажем, дают «тестовый пробег» на несколько дней с возможностью без вопросов вернуть деньги, если сервис не понравился.

Не можете купить и попробовать — найдите у знакомого на антресоли древний «celeron» этак на 633MHz и запустите там именно то, что собираетесь запускать на VPS. Пощупайте как будет производительность, интерполируйте до обещанного гигагерца. Потребление памяти посмотрите — сколько оно будет жрать там, сколько, примерно, будет и на VPS'е (при важном условии — одинаковой архитектуре, между x86 и x86_64 потребление будет различаться).

Не обижайтесь что не получаете желаемый ответ-цифру, но его действительно нельзя дать. Если только выдумать с потолка и соврать.

Comment: gephaest и drdaeman спасибо за нормальные ответы, мне ненужна была точная цифра хотя бы приблизительная.

П.С. если не joomla то какая фри CMS будет получше? WP или Drupal?